# Sorting function breaks when I try to change it to reverse alphabetical order?

Tags: c

So I have this function which currently sorts through an array struct I plug into it and sorts it alphabetically as shown:

```
void string_rearrangement(Employee payroll[], int size)
{
    //declaring temporary struct
    Employee temp;
    int i = 0, j = 0;

    for (i = 0; i <= size; i++)
    {
        for (j = i + 1; j <= size; j++)
        {
            if (strcmp(payroll[i].name, payroll[j].name) >0)
            {
                temp = payroll[i];
                payroll[i] = payroll[j];
                payroll[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

It works. I've tested it. Here's a screenshot of the output i get when I print the names: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vS7y7.png

But now I wanted to change it so it would give me the reverse alphabetical order. I thought this would just be changing the strcmp condition to <0 as shown:

```
            if (strcmp(payroll[i].name, payroll[j].name) <0)
```

But when I do that, I get some crazy output like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIUHT.png

The only thing I changed between the code was the >0 so I'm not sure why this is happening.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text, post text as text. Also show how you call the sort function. Best post a [MCVE]. You can [edit]  your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (i = 0; i <= size; i++)
{
    for (j = i + 1; j <= size; j++)
```

You should *almost certainly* use `<` instead of `<=` here. You’re running over the array bounds and into undefined behaviour. You simply got incredibly lucky that your code worked before you changed the sort order.

Comment: yep it was an array bounds issue. That fixed it. That didn't even cross my mind since it worked the first time despite the bounds issues. But thank you.